# Moving marker in a Grid Pane

Tags: javafx, grid

I have created a Grid Pane with a number of rows. A marker should only be moveable on 1 row. When moving the mouse it should move sideways only, left or right. When you click on the marker it should be locked, no more movement. It should be highlighted with a different color.
How can I achive this?
If you know any tutorials or examples please add, thanks.

Message Output:

> Executing
>   C:\Users\s22380\Desktop\temp\JavaFXApplication9\dist\run269988000\JavaFXApplication9.jar
>   using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre/bin/java
>   Exception in Application constructor
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application
>   instance: class javafxapplication9.JavaFXApplication9     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   sample.Controller.(Controller.java:33)  at
>   javafxapplication9.JavaFXApplication9.(JavaFXApplication9.java:19)
>     ... 13 more Exception running application
>   javafxapplication9.JavaFXApplication9 Java Result: 1 Deleting
>   directory
>   C:\Users\s22380\Desktop\temp\JavaFXApplication9\dist\run269988000
>   jfxsa-run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Answer (score 0):

How about this: Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    Controller controller = new Controller(10,10);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this.controller);
        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
        this.controller.InitUi();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is basically the sample code when you say new JavaFX project in IntelliJ. I changed it to explicitly set the controller. But that is just personal preference.

The xaml for that

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<GridPane fx:id="mainGrid" alignment="center" gridLinesVisible="true" hgap="10"  vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Again. Basically the default stuff.

I also added a style sheet to define the different lock for the not movable state.
redStyle.css

```
 .button {
     -fx-text-fill: #006464;
     -fx-background-color: #DFB951;
     -fx-border-radius: 20;
     -fx-background-radius: 20;
     -fx-padding: 5;
 }
```

Now for the controller.

It will do a few things:

- Listen to the mouse events of the object I want to push around. If the delata is big enough I will move it => if the mouse is moved fast enough
- When the button is pressed I will switch out the style sheet to get the different look. Right now this style works on all buttons in the scene. It could be changed to work only on a specific one.

  ```
     package sample;


  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler;
  import javafx.fxml.FXML;

  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
  import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
  import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
  import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

  public class Controller
  {
      @FXML
      private GridPane mainGrid;

      @FXML
      private Button movable;

      private final int  sizeX;
      private final int  sizeY;

      private final double minMoveDistanc = 3;

      private boolean canMove = true;

      private Double lastX = null;
      private Double lastY = null;

      private String redButtonStyle = Controller.class.getResource("redStyle.css").toExternalForm();

      public Controller(int sizeX, int sizeY)
      {
          this.sizeX = sizeX;
          this.sizeY = sizeY;
      }

      public void InitUi()
      {
          if (this.mainGrid != null)
          {
              final int numCols = sizeX;
              final int numRows = sizeY;
              for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
              {
                  ColumnConstraints colConst = new ColumnConstraints();
                  this.mainGrid.getColumnConstraints().add(colConst);
              }
              for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
              {
                  RowConstraints rowConst = new RowConstraints();
                  this.mainGrid.getRowConstraints().add(rowConst);
              }

              // add rectangle to keep grid in size
              for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
              {
                  for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
                  {
                      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                      rect.setWidth(50);
                      rect.setHeight(50);
                      this.mainGrid.add(rect,i,j);
                  }
              }

              // ad movable object (Button)
              this.movable = new Button("Hallo");
              this.movable.setPrefWidth(50);
              this.movable.setPrefHeight(50);
              this.movable.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
              {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                  {
                      canMove = ! canMove;
                      movable.setText(canMove? "move" : "stop");
                      if (canMove)
                      {
                          movable.getScene().getStylesheets().remove(redButtonStyle);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          movable.getScene().getStylesheets().add(redButtonStyle);
                      }
                  }
              });
              this.mainGrid.add(this.movable,5,5);

          }

          if (this.movable != null)
          {
              this.movable.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
              {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
                  {
                      lastX = null;
                      lastY = null;
                  }
              });

              this.movable.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
              {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
                  {
                      lastX = null;
                      lastY = null;
                  }
              });

              this.movable.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
              {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
                  {
                      if (!canMove)
                      {   return; }

                      double x = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                      double y = mouseEvent.getSceneY();

                      if (lastX == null)
                      {
                          lastX = x;
                          lastY = y;
                          return;
                      }

                      // calculate delta
                      double deltaX = x - lastX;
                      double deltaY = y - lastY;

                      // remember new position
                      lastX = x;
                      lastY = y;

                      boolean moved = false;

                      // x movement
                      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > minMoveDistanc)
                      {
                          moved = true;
                          int currentColumn = GridPane.getColumnIndex(movable);

                          if (deltaX < 0)
                          {
                              GridPane.setColumnIndex(movable, Math.max(currentColumn -1 ,0));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              GridPane.setColumnIndex(movable, Math.min(currentColumn + 1 ,sizeX-1));
                          }
                      }

                      // y movement
                      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > minMoveDistanc)
                      {
                          moved = true;
                          int currentRow = GridPane.getRowIndex(movable);

                          if (deltaY < 0)
                          {
                              GridPane.setRowIndex(movable, Math.max(currentRow - 1 ,0));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              GridPane.setRowIndex(movable, Math.min(currentRow + 1 ,sizeY-1));
                          }
                      }

                      if (moved)
                      {
                          lastX = null;
                          lastY = null;
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Many thanks for your effort and perfectly presented example. I tried it but  get an exception when running. Not exactly sure why. I havent included the css file. Where should i put it?

Comment: Just put I next to the other files `String redButtonStyle = Controller.class.getResource("redStyle.css").toExternalForm();` tries to load it from the same folder. Also: what's your exception

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at sample.Controller.(Controller.java:33) at`  controller line 33 is the loading of the style from the file. It propably can't find it. Try removing the style stuff, and check if the rest works

Comment: I have tested several times and can't get it up and running. I actually solved the problem with the css file, but now I get other exceptions. If it's possible  send working package or download link online. Thanks.